# Copy a selected row to an array that populates another UITableView in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, ios5, delegates

Here is my question: I have two UITableViewController that we're going to call. OriginalTableViewController and SecondTableViewController. 
The SecondTableViewController is populated by an NSMutableArray and a UISegmentedControl where the users can navigate through a bunch of data and select multiple rows.

What I want to do is to enable the users to select multiple row, click on save button in the navigation bar and then on OK to dismiss the view and go back to OriginalTableViewController which has to be populated by the selected rows of the SecondTableViewController.

I don't know exactly how to proceed since I started to learn how to code like 4 months ago. Should I use delegation? Or anything else? I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

For your problem, delegation would be the best choice. You define a protocol in SecondTableViewController and implement that protocol in OriginalTableViewController. When the Save button is pressed, the second table notifies the original table with selected data, and the original can pop/dismiss the second and reloads its table.

In SecondTableViewController.h, define the protocol:

```
@protocol SecondDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void) didSelectRows:(NSArray *)rows;
@end

@interface SecondTableViewController : UITableViewController
@property (retain) id<SecondDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

In OriginalTableViewController, implement the protocol:
.h:

```
@interface OriginalTableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, SecondDelegate>
```

.m:

```
- (void) didSelectRows:(NSArray *)rows {
    // Update the model with selected data and reload. Also pops/dismisses second table.
}
```

And set the delegate property just before pushing/presenting SecondTableViewController:

```
SecondTableViewController *second = nil; // instantiate the vc some how
second.delegate = self;
```

In SecondTableViewController.m, implement the save method:

```
- (void) save {
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows]) {
        // Populate array with selected objects.
    }
    [self.delegate didSelectRows:array];
}
```

Hope this helps.